# Pass annotation to a function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, cdi

How can I pass an annotion instance to a function?

I would like to call the java method `AbstractCDI.select(Class<T> type, Annotation... qualifiers)`. But I don't know how to pass an annotation instance to this method.

Calling the constructor like
`cdiInstance.select(MyClass::javaClass, MyAnnotation())`
 is not allowed and the @Annotation-Syntax `cdiInstance.select(MyClass::javaClass, @MyAnnotation)` is not allowed as parameter, too. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `CDI` you usually also have [`AnnotationLiteral`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) available or at least you can implement something similar rather easy.

If you want to select a class using your annotation the following should do the trick:

```
cdiInstance.select(MyClass::class.java, object : AnnotationLiteral<MyAnnotation>() {})
```

Or you may need to implement your specific `AnnotationLiteral`-class if you require a specific value. In Java that would work as follows:

```
class MyAnnotationLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<MyAnnotation> implements MyAnnotation {
    private String value;

    public MyAnnotationLiteral(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String[] value() {
        return new String[] { value };
    }
 }
```

In Kotlin however, you can't implement the annotation and extend `AnnotationLiteral` or maybe I just did not see how (see also related question: [Implement (/inherit/~extend) annotation in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608924/implement-inherit-extend-annotation-in-kotlin)).

If you rather want to continue using reflection to access the annotation then you should probably rather use the Kotlin reflection way instead:

```
ClassWithAnno::class.annotations
ClassWithAnno::methodWithAnno.annotations
```

Calling `filter`, etc. to get the `Annotation` you desire or if you know there is only one `Annotation` there, you can also just call the following (`findAnnotation` is an extension function on `KAnnotatedElement`):

```
ClassWithAnno::class.findAnnotation<MyAnnotation>()
ClassWithAnno::methodWithAnno.findAnnotation<MyAnnotation>()
```

Comment: Thank you! AnnotationLiteral was exactly what I searched for!

Comment: You are welcome! Note, that I added also a question regarding implementation of `AnnotationLiteral` for cases where you need to specify custom values (e.g. to narrow which qualifier should be taken). If you don't require that you are lucky and `AnnotationLiteral` will work as is. If you do, then you may need to use a Java implementation as workaround for now as Kotlin doesn't seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

One could annotate a method or field with the annotation an get it per Reflection:

`this.javaClass.getMethod("annotatedMethod").getAnnotation(MyAnnotation::class.java)`

Or According to Roland's suggestion the kotlin version of the above:

`MyClass::annotatedMethod.findAnnotation<MyAnnotation>()!!`

As suggested by Roland for CDI it is better to use `AnnotationLiteral` (see his post).