# Kotlin method overloading

Tags: java, kotlin, overloading, java-interop

This following declaration is legal in Kotlin.

```
fun foo(): String = "foo_1"
fun <T> foo(): T = "foo_2" as T
```

As bytecode we are getting:

```
public final static foo()Ljava/lang/String;

// signature <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>()TT;
// declaration: T foo<T>()
public final static foo()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

It's also possible to call both of these methods from Kotlin.

The problem comes when I'm trying to call any of them from Java:

```
ClassKt.foo()
```

> Ambiguous call. Both methods match ...

How to avoid such a problem? How to deal with such methods? What if 3-rd party kt library has same issue?

The example above is a synthetic  one.

Comment: The last part is easy: when a 3rd party library does that, you can write up a defect and ask them to solve the problem :-).. Beyond that, the possible answer is: don't overload your methods like this then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Why* does it work with Kotlin to begin with... In Java having two methods like:

```
private static String test() {
    return "";
}

private static <T> T test() {
    return null;
}
```

would result in a compile time error. And for java devs this is sort of obvious, these methods would have the same type erasure. *But* this is rule imposed by `javac`, *not* by the `JVM` where this code runs. So `javac` does not treat two methods as having *only* a different return type as overloads. Well, `kotlin` is a different language and since it runs on the `JVM` (that expects valid byte-code) it allows treating methods with *only* the return type being different as overloads. I am yet to look at the byte code and understand how that happens; it also seems that this will work only for generic code, so may be type erasure is slightly different in case of kotlin.

Now, things should be obvious why calling such a method from java fails. Kotlin offers a neat solution for this: `@JvmName("someDistinctName")`. I am not entirely sure how this works under the hood either... yet, though I assume this will create a bridge method.

**EDIT**

`@JvmName` will rename the method at the byte-code level.

Comment: Yes, this make sense. I understand that language level and vm bytecode level has different "restrictions". But still - where is 100% interop in this case?

Comment: I came to this example from the more complicated one. If we will add `suspend` modifier to both kotlin methods - bytecode will become much more interesting.

Comment: I gave an [answer regarding 'How does erasure work in Kotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653302/6202869) which also highlights some of this if you are interested (and some links how you could use something similar in Java). There are also other things that aren't 100% compatible, but the other way around, e.g. try to [implement an annotation in Kotlin (in Java it works, in Kotlin it doesn't (yet?))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608924/implement-inherit-extend-annotation-in-kotlin).

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin not entirely sure I follow you when you say *where is 100% interop in this case?*. what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@JvmName](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname) to differentiate the code when it's called from java:

```
@JvmName("fooString")
fun foo(): String = "foo_1"

fun <T> foo(): T = "foo_2" as T
```

This will allow calling the String method in Java with `ClassKt.fooString()`, which resolves the clash.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be writing a helper method in Kotlin and just calling that.

---

Another way using only Java would be getting a `MethodHandle` for both methods and using them:

```
MethodHandle MH_fooString = lookup().findStatic(ClassKt.class, "foo", methodType(String.class));
MethodHandle MH_fooT = lookup().findStatic(ClassKt.class, "foo", methodType(Object.class));

String foo = (String) MH_fooString.invokeExact();
```

It's not nearly as simple and requires handling exceptions though.

Comment: and will be slower than a usual method invocation

Comment: @Eugene I don't think there will be any significant performance difference if you store the MethodHandles in static final fields. It shouldn't be very hard to optimize.

Comment: this is almost a reflective call, it does not matter where it is stored, and compared to a plain method call it should be significant.

Comment: @Eugene It's nothing like a reflective call though as the method is statically known and optimizable by JIT. With enough warm-up I could only see < 1% difference between the two in a simple test I did. Either way, I doubt the performance even matters in this specific case.