# Kotlin annotation alias

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, alias, type-alias

Is it somehow possible to have "annotation aliases" in Kotlin?

What I want to achieve is to transform this

```
@Colour("red")
fun method() = "something"
```

into something like this

```
annotationalias Red = Colour("red")

@Red
fun method() = "something"
```

Comment: That would be a cool feature, but it is currently not in Kotlin. You need to write your own annotation called `Red`, and write your own annotation processor that translates it into `Colour("red")`.

Comment: If you have control over the processor that's reading the annotations, you can change it to search for aliases manually. Some libraries already include this, like Spring Boot's [meta-annotations and composed annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-meta-annotations).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/55711084/4161471